# Where can I find a good Starcraft 2 community to learn how to play the game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to find a good SC2 community to learn how to play the game and eventually move up to league play.  Any good recommendations?

Comment: We have [quite a library](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) of information for strategies in this game. Why not learn with us? ♪

Comment: I agree when you have a specific question our site is one of the best for getting answers, but for a lot of lower level players they have no idea what their missing until a commentator describes the reason a pro chooses to do the things they do.  Day9 is so popular because he discusses all decisions at a near meta-game level.  Just being exposed to that sort of talent can really help build orders, micro, macro, timings, and game sense.

Comment: I don't think I really agree with this question being on-topic for the site. We've closed other questions in the past regarding finding clans/guilds/etc. in order to prevent promotion of any one site over another because any answers we can give would likely turn into a popularity contest.

Comment: @Fall Is [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/where-can-i-find-serious-teammates-in-modern-warfare-2-closed) perhaps one of the questions you were looking for on chat?

Comment: I also agree this is a bad question.  We have a lot of information on learning here if you want it. Otherwise look to any of the major SC2 Teams: Evil Geniuses, Meet Your Makers, Team Liquid.

Comment: I find this question to be very subjective.  Much like recommending a game, recommending resources is also based on personal preference.  Like recommending a game, answers are voted for their references not the quality of their write up.  Perhaps this is a good topic for discussion in the Meta once game references have been resolved.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**

This question is quite subjective, so I want to add this disclaimer to the top of it to avoid getting down-voted further.  These are links that have worked for me, and helped me to improve as a player.  People will learn by a variety of methods, but I have found these a good place to start.

Starcraft 2 has the significant advantage over previous RTS games with shoutcasts (when commentators explain recorded games), large communities, and a growing professional gaming scene.  Here are a list of my favorite starcraft links.

[Day9 Daily: daily video with very deep strategic analysis](http://youtube.com/day9tv)

[Husky Starcraft: professional gamer commentary](http://youtube.com/huskystarcraft)

[Hd Starcraft: professional gamer commentary](http://youtube.com/hdstarcraft)

[Team Liquid: Korean Starcraft team, amazing strategy forum](http://teamliquid.net)

Hope these help!

Comment: These are all great sources, and I plan on taking a closer look at them in the coming weeks.  I am still curious about how to find a "community" to belong to.  I really miss the feeling of being a part of a gaming community similar to the one I belonged to back in my COD2 days.  Any recommendations for a community?

Comment: Absolutely, team liquid is probably the biggest possible starcraft community, but that in itself turns me off to it.  If you want a great starcraft community log on for the day9 daily live stream.  It's not only the best resource for improving your game but it also has a community built around that.  In addition to that try finding a clan to play starcraft with.  You can find these through team liquid.  A clan provides you with practice players of your skill (or better) that you can improve with and try and apply what you learn from day9.

Comment: I actually think HD and Husky are really bad sources.  You should be looking towards Teams (Evil Geniuses, Meet your Maker, Team Liquid) not commentators

Comment: Commentators are fine to learn the game, because really all they are doing is narrating some pro 1v1 games. However the only thing you can really learn from those games is some tips and tricks on unit micro, not economy control or macro. I just watch them to get hope that Protoss aren't always destroyed by Terran (even though it seems like it). Team Liquid is the biggest community for sure.

Comment: @Resorath I could not disagree stronger on the issue of Commentators.  More often than what Pros are doing in their matches is so far above when the average player needs to focus on that it actually distracts new players from where they should focus their time.  While these commentators will do the occasional break down of a low level game, these are few and far between (though I will give credit to Day9 on this particular issue).  What a new player who's trying to get into the scene needs to focus on is Execution, and that's something that you only learn from a good community like TL.

Comment: Agreed with @Tzenes. The "mistakes" that are pointed out in pro games are often extremely minor compared to the mistakes that new players make. The difference being that pros generally don't make basic mistakes, so they aren't there to point out. If a new player focuses on not making the mistakes pros make, they may end up making other bigger mistakes.  In pro games 10 seconds is a long time and being 5-10 seconds slow on a build will usually cost you the game, whereas in lower levels that amount if time is usually negligible compared to the many other mistakes players make.

Comment: When i first played SC2 shortly after release i only watched Husky, HD and Day9 and got to Diamond after a few weeks anyways, so i don't think it hurts watching commentators and especially Husky has a way of making you want to play more (which is a good thing) and recently also makes me want to build more banelings :). What i really suggest though are streams of players playing the game. There are always some available through TeamLiquid. Live Streams help you see _how_ they do the amazing stuff they do in tournaments.

Comment: Team Liquid was founded by and consists of mostly Europeans. They've never had a Korean player on their roster.

Comment: +1'd for Day9.  Definitely by far and away one of the best resources.